# int vs short vectorization

Tags: c, performance, sse

I have the following kernel vectorized for arrays with integers:

```
    long valor = 0, i=0;

    __m128i vsum, vecPi, vecCi, vecQCi;

    vsum = _mm_set1_epi32(0);

    int32_t * const pA = A->data;
    int32_t * const pB = B->data;

    int sumDot[1];

    for( ; i<SIZE-3 ;i+=4){
            vecPi = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&(pA)[i] );
            vecCi = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&(pB)[i] );
            vecQCi = _mm_mullo_epi32(vecPi,vecCi);
            vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum,vecQCi);
    }

    vsum = _mm_hadd_epi32(vsum, vsum);
    vsum = _mm_hadd_epi32(vsum, vsum);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&(sumDot), vsum);

    for( ; i<SIZE; i++)
          valor += A->data[i] * B->data[i];

    valor += sumDot[0];
```

and it works fine. However, if I change the datatype of A and B to **short** instead of **int**, shouldn't I use the following code:

```
    long valor = 0, i=0;

    __m128i vsum, vecPi, vecCi, vecQCi;

    vsum = _mm_set1_epi16(0);

    int16_t * const pA = A->data;
    int16_t * const pB = B->data;

    int sumDot[1];

    for( ; i<SIZE-7 ;i+=8){
            vecPi = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&(pA)[i] );
            vecCi = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&(pB)[i] );
            vecQCi = _mm_mullo_epi16(vecPi,vecCi);
            vsum = _mm_add_epi16(vsum,vecQCi);
    }

    vsum = _mm_hadd_epi16(vsum, vsum);
    vsum = _mm_hadd_epi16(vsum, vsum);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&(sumDot), vsum);

    for( ; i<SIZE; i++)
          valor += A->data[i] * B->data[i];

    valor += sumDot[0];
```

This second kernel doesn't work and I don't know why. I know that all the entries of the vectors in the first and second case are the same (no overflow as well). Can someone help me finding the mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few things I see.

1. In both the `int` and `short` case, when you're storing the `__m128` to `sumDot`, you use `_mm_storeu_si128` on targets that are *much smaller* than 128 bits. This means you've been corrupting memory, and were lucky you were not bitten.

   - Related to this, because `sumDot` is an `int[1]` even in the `short` case, you were storing *two* `short`s in one `int`, and then reading it as an `int`.
2. In the `short` case you're missing one horizontal vector reduction step. Remember that now that you've got 8 `short`s per vector, you must now have log_2(8) = 3 vector reduction steps.

   ```
   vsum = _mm_hadd_epi16(vsum, vsum);
   vsum = _mm_hadd_epi16(vsum, vsum);
   vsum = _mm_hadd_epi16(vsum, vsum);
   ```
3. (Optional) Since you're onto SSE4.1 already, might as well use one of the goodies it has: The `PEXTR*` instructions. They take the index of the lane from which to extract. You're interested in the bottom lane (lane 0) because that's where the sum ends up after your vector reduction.

   ```
   /* 32-bit */
   sumDot[0] = _mm_extract_epi32(vsum, 0);
   /* 16-bit */
   sumDot[0] = _mm_extract_epi16(vsum, 0);
   ```

   ***EDIT***: Apparently the compiler *doesn't* sign-extend the 16-bit word extracted with `_mm_extract_epi16`. You must convince it to do so yourself.

   ```
   /* 32-bit */
   sumDot[0] = (int32_t)_mm_extract_epi32(vsum, 0);
   /* 16-bit */
   sumDot[0] = (int16_t)_mm_extract_epi16(vsum, 0);
   ```

   ***EDIT2***: I found an even BETTER solution! It uses exactly the instruction we need (`PMADDWD`), and is *identical* to the 32-bit code except that the iteration bounds are different, and instead of `_mm_mullo_epi16` you use `_mm_madd_epi16` in the loop. This only needs two 32-bit vector reduction stages. http://pastebin.com/A9ibkMwP
4. (Optional) It is good style but will make no difference to use the `_mm_setzero_*()` functions instead of `_mm_set1_*(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments. I really appreciate them! The result is still different, though.

Comment: @a3mlord When you say that the entries are the same in both tests, do you mean that the same buffers are passed in, or that you've reinitialized the buffers with the same values, but in a smaller type?

Comment: I've filled the arrays with the same values but in a smaller type.

Comment: @a3mlord Just curious; Is the number of `short`s you're passing in a multiple of 8?

Comment: @a3mlord In any case could you post up your corrected code on say Pastebin so that I can figure out why it's still not behaving? I'm at a loss to guess what else may be wrong.

Comment: No, I am passing random numbers (within the bounds of short). It might be that some are in fact multiples of 8, but it won't be more often than any other number. The code has 16K lines of code, its kinda impossible to put it in pastbin. Is there anything in particular that you would like me to put there? Thanks

Comment: BTW, did you notice that "valor" is a long? Can I make this += operation between a long and the bottom lane of a __m128i register?

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist forgot to @ you.

Comment: @a3mlord In fact, making the `valor` variable a `long` probably won't make a difference assuming you're correct about no overflow - normal C sign-extension rules apply here. The thing that's key here is that after selecting the value of Lane 0 with PEXTR(W|D) you now have a proper scalar; While with `_mm_storeu_si128` you were storing two lanes into one int, and six lanes beyond it, corrupting who knows what.

Comment: @a3mlord I found the reason!

Comment: @a3mlord The problem was that with 16-bit PEXTR the compiler wasn't sign-extending the extracted value (even though `_mm_extract_epi16()`'s return type is `int`). Look at my edit under 3 and test case here: http://pastebin.com/H0tJRM0E

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist In that case I must have mistakes elsewhere. The result is still not correct. I am printing the "valor" variable within the function that vectorizes ints and the reduction that vectorizes shorts, and it is different. All the other values (values in the arrays, for example, are the same. Very weird!

Comment: @a3mlord But does my Pastebin testcase work? If it doesn't, then I'm still missing something, if not then at least we can close out this part and look at the rest of your code.

Comment: I am compiling with : g++ *.c *.cpp *.a *.h -g -msse4.1 -march=corei7-avx -mtune=corei7-avx -mno-avx -mno-aes -Warray-bounds -fopenmp -O0 -I /usr/local/include -I . -lm

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist yes, it does. I compiled your code and it works. However, in the other code, it doesn't. It is very weird that it doesn't work there, because the values are all the same!

Comment: Using a debugger, can you confirm the arguments to the dot-product function really are the same (and haven't been corrupted by the time the call is made)? Also, can you dump out the disassembly of this kernel?

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist Just did. In both cases the arrays have: $1 = {169, -341, 487, -50, 116, -66, 170, -217, -236, 72, -296, -469, -178, -1, 61, -26, -107, 593, -558, 125, 111, 111, 184, 141, -228, -490, -357, 535, 206, -85, -29, -216, -490, -265, 12, 250, 306, 
  -291, -46, 180} ......... and ........ $2 = {398, 305, 268, -125, -96, -214, -284, 108, -37, 2, -402, -228, 243, 33, 76, 265, 3, -558, -323, -552, 419, 408, -217, -2, -440, -375, 153, -108, -79, -80, 299, 81, -385, 80, 53, 294, 170, -380, 
  -164, -172}

Comment: @a3mlord The fact that their dot-products are _568958_ for 32-bit and _-20866_ for 16-bit, and that (568958--20866)/32768 == 18, is a hint that overflow is occurring. In fact you can't even store close to even one-eight of 560958 in a signed short. And your very first multiplication already overflows: 169*398 = 67262.

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist I thought about that, but it would also overflow for integers, no? With integers, everythings allright.

Comment: @a3mlord Well, no, because `int` is 32-bit wide and ranges from -2147483648 to 2147483647 while `short` is 16-bit wide and ranges from -32768 to 32767. Even if all your values were positive and added together you wouldn't have gotten close to `INT_MAX`, whereas just your first multiplication overflows `SHORT_MAX`. Information is therefore lost.

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist You're totally right, but more than one author said to use shorts in this code (and we can assume those values as representative) and argue to vectorize them. I am confused... Well is there anything else I can do on the Sandy Bridge architecture?

Comment: @a3mlord The values given here have products slightly outside the range of short. If you're determined to use `short`, you will therefore have to use not only `_mm_mullo_epi16` but also (luckily for you, SSE has this) `_mm_mulhi_epi16`, and somehow detect overflows in the low part and accumulate the carries into the high part.

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist are you aware of any link where I can look at examples? BTW, thanks a LOT for your help!

Comment: I'm just about to write a small example with `_mm_mulhi`, just wait a sec (I'm actually only stumped on how to detect unsigned overflow) Here: http://pastebin.com/PUDaSV7h

Comment: @a3mlord All you need to in http://pastebin.com/PUDaSV7h now is to figure out how to correctly detect unsigned addition overflow in `detectOVF()` and for each lane in which overflow will occur, return a value with the sign bit set in that lane.

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist the code that you have there doesn't work. Should I now try to correct detectOVF()? Example: Failure! (32: 568958 != -283010 : 16)

Comment: @a3mlord Yes, that's what I'm trying to correct myself right now.

Comment: @a3mlord Never mind detecting overflow, I found an even better solution! Check EDIT2. It uses a different instruction that does exactly what we want. PMADDWD multiplies point-wise 16-bit signed integers to 32-bit intermediates, adds adjacent intermediates together and saves the result to the destination. Just what you needed. http://pastebin.com/A9ibkMwP

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist I just saw this. Thanks a LOT ;-)

Comment: @ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist Thanks a LOT for your help, I really appreciate it! However, the speedup is minimal (0.05x in the whole app, whereas I had 2x with SSE on ints), cuz we're still using a lot of 32 bit operations. Can we turn this in 16-bit operations by any chance?

Comment: @Idonotexist, unfortunately, I can't optimize this further. Any assistance is appreciated! thanks

Comment: @a3mlord To be clear, it's the version with the `PMADDWD` instruction that isn't any faster than the original `int`? That's odd, it's almost ideally suited for what we need and after the multiplies it leaves 32-bit values to add...

Comment: @Idonotexist it is faster, but not too much (only 4-5%), because we have a _mm_add_epi32 and the sum reduction also in 32 bits. Is there any way of replacing everything to epi16 instructions?